# bash - How to detect if my file is in a (sub)folder

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script to move files after use them in bash.
I'm using "open with" my script, so `$1` is the file (fullpath)

```
#! /bin/bash

fullpath="$1"
rootpath="/home/guillaume/Videos"
foo=${fullpath#${rootpath}}
echo "$foo"

zenity --question --title="Déplacer le fichier ?" --text="Déplacer le fichier vers le dossier VU ?"
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    if # foo don't have a folder
    then
       mv $rootpath"$foo" /home/guillaume/Videos/VU
    elif # foo contains a folder
       # command to copy the subdirectory
    fi
fi
```

The result for `foo` could be:

```
/title_subdirectory/file with_spaces or_not.ext
```

or

```
/file with_spaces or_not.ext
```

How to detect if the file is in a subdirectory, and then, move all the subdirectory and the files ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check if the file name is the same as it's `basename` (name without directory)

```
if [ `basename "$foo"` = "$foo" ] ; then
  echo root directory
else
  echo subdirectory
fi
```

If files in your root directory have a leading `/` then you may need to do it like this to strip the leading `/` before comparison:

```
if [ `basename "$foo"` = "${foo#/}" ] ; then
  echo root directory
else
  echo subdirectory
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using `base=$(basename "$foo")` and `complete="${foo#/}"`, then I compare both stings.